# Only show specific sheet in the embed Google Spread

Tags: google-sheets, html

Can I embed a specific sheet not the whole spreadsheet in html webpage?

```
<iframe height="500" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<key>/edit?usp=sharing" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful info [from documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en) will help:

> To publish a file:
>
> 1. Open a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing.
> 2. Click the File menu.
> 3. Select Publish to the Web.
> 4. While the entire file will be published, some file types have more    publishing options: Spreadsheet: Choose to publish the entire
>      spreadsheet or individual sheets. You can also choose a publishing
>      format (web page, .csv, .tsv, .pdf, .xlsx, .ods).
> 5. Click Publish.
> 6. Copy the URL and send it to anyone you’d like to see the file. Or,
>      embed it into your website.

If you choose *Embed* in step 4,

[image]

you'll get this code:

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S14JwcYCN30VlFG0ZsBS0kHOT1_AkGxV_HydQ5-UFcI/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe></div>`